# Compute and add X-Content-Duration header for .ogg files to nginx

Tags: nginx, ogg

I am using nginx to serve `.mp3` and `.ogg` files. The article [Configuring servers for Ogg media](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Configuring_servers_for_Ogg_media) suggests to add the `X-Content-Duration` header when serving `.ogg` files to avoid that the browser has to seek in order to determine the audio length.

[Oggz](http://www.xiph.org/oggz/) is able to compute the length of an `.ogg` audio file.

How can I configure nginx to automatically invoke Oggz to compute the length of the audio, cache it, and add it to the headers when serving the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [Lua](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLuaModule#ngx.header.HEADER) and would try to avoid a shell call by using lua itself to parse the ogg headers.

Comment: I also thought about Lua, but the catch with Ogg is that it doesn't encapsulate the length of the media.

Comment: You might be able to borrow from [this music player](http://code.google.com/p/lomp/source/browse/trunk/modules/fileinfo/ogg.lua?spec=svn216&r=216).